# What Database do OAuth Providers like Google,Facebook,Apple,Github,Microsoft,etc use to store various log of various websites?

Tags: database, logging, oauth-2.0, oauth, database-schema

What should be the ideal database-schema if you are building an Oauth Provider and store session timings?

Answer (score 1):

https://auth0.com/blog/how-we-store-data-in-the-cloud-at-auth0/ Auth0 uses MongoDB.

I assume it has everything to do with the 'More reads less writes' motto that defines NoSQL. Plus many mongo specific features like Replication, which help keep the integrity of the user data.

For logging specifically, Microsoft recommends Azure Blob Storage [ABS for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#what-is-blob-storage) and other providers like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/).

NoSQL db's like MongoDB don't follow a rigid schema, and logs could be stored in an unstructured data storage, but the modern way is using Object Storage which various cloud providers provide. Unstructured data is simply storing data without any schema, relation or clear structure. Object Storage is storing the same things without any folders or subdirectories, plus defining some metadata for each file and is a better way of storing logs like session-timings.